# Is Django is an appropriate tool for what I'm trying to do?

Tags: python, html, django

I have experience using HTML/CSS/Javascript and Python separately, but I'm completely lost on how to use both together (if that's even a thing). I have a Python file that can take input, calculate a value and return it. I thought my final result would be a webpage coded using HTML/CSS, that took a user input, inserted it somehow into that Python file and displayed the output.

When I began reading about using Python in webpages, the most popular recommendation seemed to use the framework Django. While going through the tutorial however, Django seemed possibly overkill for what I was trying to do. Is using Django the best way to take user inputs, run Python on them, and display the output to the user?

Comment: I'm actually in your same boat. Looking forward to answers

Comment: This is pretty a pretty broad question. But yeah, Django has a lot of stuff you wouldn't likely use for such a simple case. I would probably go with a lighterweight framework like flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider micro frameworks like Flask. It's a lot simpler and smaller compared to Django.

- Flask:http://flask.pocoo.org/
- Bottle: https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

I'm sure there's more but you can start with those two.